# Ansible - Using a var from an inventory

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible inventory file my_inv.yml where I have something this:

```
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
  children:
    my_env1:
      hosts:
        my_env.app.domain.com
      vars:
        my_var_1: "True"
        my_var_2: '123'
    my_env2:
      hosts:
        my_env2.app.domain.com
      vars:
        my_var_1: "True"
        my_var_2: '123'
  ...
```

I am running a script (myscript.sh env) to call a playbook. Inside that script, It's something like this:

```
ENVIR="${1}"

ansible-playbook -i inventory/my_inv.yml --extra-vars "ENV=$ENVIR MY_VAR={{hostvars[ENV]['my_var_1']}"
```

So I want to capture my_var_1 (value true) for my_env1, and send it in the extra-vars. This is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: you cant do that the var hostvars.... is known only when the ansible-playbook launches the playbook...

Comment: So if I run the first playbook without the - - extra-vars, than I can catch the variable my_var_1?

Comment: yes inside task you could trap all hostvars

Comment: ok, so if i need to call a playbook2 from playbook1, and send that var from playbook1 to playbook2, how can i achieve it?

Comment: are you using same hosts with your 2 playbooks?

Comment: The hosts are the same but for each one I have and inventory where I have the vars defined.

Comment: I managed to do it using the tipo you told me: i CALL THE playbook and after that I called the var just using; {{ my_var_1 }}. I guess when I call the playbook, and defining my_env1, ansible know the value of the var my_var_1 for the called env.

Answer (score 0):

you could launch this playbook by specifying the var ENV in the command:

```
- name: "tips4"
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false


  tasks: 
     
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names.0}}"
   
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['my_var_1']}}"
      when: "hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names.0 == ENV"

    - set_fact:
        toto: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['my_var_1']}}"
      when: "hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names.0 == ENV"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ toto}}"
      when: toto is defined
```